# Disable transitive PackageReference dependency for a specific MsBuild project

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017, nuget, transitive-dependency, packagereference

I am migrating an old style MsBuild csproj project to using PackageReference format and have run into a problem with transitive dependencies.

Consider the following
Project A reference NuGet package B and C, each containing one single assembly using PackageReference.
On Build Project A uses IL merge to incorporate B as public symbols in the A assembly and C as internalized symbols.
Project D have a project reference to A.

The transitive dependencies case D to reference A, B and C.
When building D, compile errors of the type
error CS0433: The type 'X' exists in both 'A' and 'B' 
occur.

Is there any way to force D to not add an explicit reference to B or C in the scenario above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up using a [workaround](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4989#issuecomment-310565840) to move the transitive dependency to an alias to get around the compiler error.

```xml
<Target Name="ChangeAliasesOfBNameAssemblies" BeforeTargets="FindReferenceAssembliesForReferences;ResolveReferences">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ReferencePath Condition="'%(FileName)' == 'B'">
      <Aliases>nonmerged</Aliases>
    </ReferencePath>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

I tried to use private assets but couldn't get the compiler error to go away in that way.

Comment: This worked for me! I didn't realize that aliasing the package I _didn't_ want to use would cause the types from the other one to be usable, so I kept trying to alias the package I _did_ want (which was a problem, because it was `Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms`...)

Comment: WOW, impressive. your approach just helped me solve an "ambiguous reference" error. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

> Disable transitive PackageReference dependency for a specific MsBuild project

If I understand you correct, you can try to use property `<PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>`or `PrivateAssets="all"` for the `PackageReference`. If you have a package that's marked with private assets it merely prevents it from flowing to parent project or getting packed.

[image]

```
<PackageReference Include="B" Version="1.0.0" PrivateAssets="all">
<PackageReference Include="C" Version="1.0.0" PrivateAssets="all">
```

You can check the document [Controlling dependency assets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#controlling-dependency-assets) and [this thread](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/6614#issuecomment-370322657) for some details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried using PrivateAssets in A's reference to B and C, but I still got the conflicting types. I ended up using the workaround here https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4989#issuecomment-310565840 to put B in a non-used alias.

Comment: @ViktorGriph, Glad to know that you have resolved this issue. Would you please post your workaround as answer, this can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread and easier find the answer :).

Comment: This doesn't resolve the issue for us.  We need a way to ignore transitive dependencies in the PackageReference paradigm similar to the way we could in the packages.config paradigm, by just removing the references that nuget added.  PrivateAssets only affects the output directory, it does not affect the dependency graph.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for this too and this answer kept popping up in google searches, but it didn't have the solution I know off (but can never remember), so I'll add my answer for future reference.

`PrivateAssets` can be used to hide many things, but hiding `all` is a bad move imo. You want *some* assets to move transitively, for example, for your app to run after a `dotnet publish`, you'll need the assemblies you need, at runtime. Hiding `all` assets means that when publishing, you may  miss a few critical things - similar to deleting some files from the output.

From reading [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#controlling-dependency-assets) on the subject, I think what I want to hide, in order to not transitively be able to compile up against an assembly (but still have it at runtime), is `compile`. So I'll set my `PrivateAssets` to `contentfiles;analyzers;build;compile`. This should mean that if `MyLibraryB` depends on `NugetPackageA` - then `MyAppC` depending on `MyLibraryB` will be able to run and publish correctly, without being able to use any classes or code from `NugetPackageA`.

Note: This of course means that `MyLibraryB` must not expose any public API that uses types found in `NugetPackageA`. The consumer won't be able to use those public API's, at least not without themselves also referencing `NugetPackageA`.

Comment: This was our scenario, hiding a 3rd party dependency from having its types appear in our consumers' scope while still being able to use it ourselves. Setting `PrivateAssets` this way seems to have done the trick.