# Type exists in 2 assemblies (due to Package dependency)

Tags: c#, nuget

I am facing the very same problem as in [Type exists in 2 assemblies](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9194495/3096657):

> The type  exists in both <ASSEMBLY1.dll> and <ASSEMBLY2.dll>

I have tried the most [voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17651003/3096657) from the question however, **I am still getting the error**. 
I believe it is because my setup is quite different from the question: I have two my projects `ProjectA` and `ProjectB`, each of those using completely *different* NuGet packages, that happen to use a dependencies/types with exactly same name but from different vendors (without vendor prefix!). Both of these projects are referenced in `ProjectC`

```
ProjectA
- Packages
-- UnrelatedPackage1
--- Dependency (VendorA)
ProjectB
- Packages
-- UnrelatedPackage2
--- Dependency (VendorB)
ProjectC
- Refences
-- ProjectA
-- ProjectB
```

Now, I would like to catch in `ProjectC`'s code an exception raised in `ProjectA`'s dependency :

```
try {
   ProjectA.SomeClass.DoStuff();
}
catch (ExceptionFromDependency ex)
{ }
```

but I cannot since

> The type ExceptionFromDependency  exists in both <Dependency
>   (VendorA)> and <Dependency (VendorB)>

I have added an alias `projectb` to `ProjectB`'s reference in `ProejctC` as recommended in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17651003/3096657), but it did not fix the error - probably because the source is not the project itself but rather dependency of dependency. 
How can I fix the error so I can catch the exception? I dont ever plan to use any types from 'Dependency (VendorB)', and I would prefer to contain its existence to the `ProjectB`, if that offers simpler solution.

Comment: To add a bit meta information: the dependency in question used by different packages is a MySql adapter and the exception in question is MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException, but the question is about this dependency issue in general.

Comment: You can try setting `<PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>` for the `PackageReference` of the `UnrelatedPackage2` in `ProjectB`. Doing so, you will prevent the references of that package (and its dependencies) from being visible up-stream (`ProjectB` and `ProjectC`).

Comment: @dymanoid Sadly, `<PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>` has no effect what so ever. All packages are still visible up-stream and the error is still there. That however brought me to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52214728/3096657) with similar problem under completely different name, where it was also suggest and likewise did not work. Luckily the other answer did.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [workaround](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4989#issuecomment-310565840) to alias the [package itself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52252705/3096657), but not accessible from UI, edit&add the following `Target` to `ProjectC`'s .csproj file:

```
<Target Name="ChangeAliasesOfAssemblies"
        BeforeTargets="FindReferenceAssembliesForReferences;ResolveReferences">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ReferencePath Condition="'%(FileName)' == 'Dependency.VendorB'">
      <Aliases>projectb</Aliases>
    </ReferencePath>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

where `Dependency.VendorB` is the .dll file name without extension of the 'Dependency (VendorB)' package. Clean/rebuild/restart IDE.