# How to specify a local source for Install-Package

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

My goal is conveniently adding my own library to my projects within my local network. I put the library in a SMB shared directory.

```
Get-Package -Source \\my\share\nuget -ListAvailable
```

showed the package. But when I tried

```
Install-Package ClassLibrary1 -Source \\my\share\nuget
```

VS ignored that source because of transient management or something and installed it from nuget.org. I searched the web and found [this existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60855372/how-to-disable-transitive-package-management-for-a-visual-studio-project), but adding that SMB share to VS's source list (after nuget.org) did not work because it still get it from nuget.org. I tried to specify the source like

```
Install-Package ClassLibrary1 -Source Local
```

where "Local" was the name I used in VS, but it did not work either. How can I make a local source work within my local network?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/ps-reference/ps-ref-install-package) we can see that:

> The URL or folder path for the package source to search. Local folder
> paths can be absolute, or relative to the current folder. If omitted,
> Install-Package searches the currently selected package source.

`\\my\share\nuget` is a [UNC path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/file-path-formats#unc-paths). So this path format doesn't work for "-source"：
[image]

You can uncheck nuget.org in package sources, clear the nuget cache and then use this command to install the package.

Comment: The MS page only explains "nuget", not VS's PM console, and I thought they were basically the same thing. MS's page had an example like `nuget add new_package.1.0.0.nupkg -source \\myserver\packages`. So, a UNC path be used with "nuget -source", but not with "Install-Package -source"?

Comment: [The nuget command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-exe-cli-reference) is different from [the powershell command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/powershell-reference). VS's PM console use PowerShell command. We can see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/cli-reference/cli-ref-add)"Specifies the package source, which is a folder or UNC share, to which the nupkg will be added. Http sources are not supported." So I think nuget commands can work with UNC paths but powershell commands can't.