Prevent Nuget package to be used outside of project
I have a C# project Wrapper.csproj that will act as a wrapper around the Nuget package Azure.Storage.Blobs.
Another project Hello.csproj will now reference Wrapper.csproj, so it can use the methods I created.
Unfortunately, it is now possible to use the classes from Azure.Storage.Blobs inside the Hello.csproj project, which seems to be transitively available via Wrapper.csproj.
Why do I want to do this? We want to prevent developers in our company from using the Nuget package classes directly, so it will be easier to migrate to a different Nuget package in the future. Right now we are in the situation that we have to migrate, and the code is spread all over the code base, which makes it difficult.
I tried using <PrivateAssets>:
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.19.1">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>

In my IDE, the Nuget package's classes are now no longer available:
Cannot resolve symbol 'BlobClient'
I removed the code shown in the screenshot, so there are no direct usages of the Nuget package outside of the wrapper. I ran my code, but unfortunately I got this:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException
Could not load file or assembly 'Azure.Storage.Blobs, Version=12.19.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8'. The system cannot find the file specified.

I have played around with all the various values that I can set with <PrivateAssets>, but I couldn't make it work.

This may be similar. See if this answer will suffice: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72923379/6594467

@Hank Amazing, thank you! If you want to post this as an official answer, I'd be happy to mark it as solved.

If that link answers the question, then the correct way to handle this is to close this question as a duplicate and point to the other one
